# Regex get MatchCollection with the individual parts of a nested multi-part data string sequence

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with many sequence of this [regex online link here](https://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/325):

```
#BEGIN
My contents, Multi-line. Anything here...
~!@#@#$
...
#END
#BEGIN
My contents, Multi-line. Anything here...
~!@#@#$
...
#END
#BEGIN
My contents, Multi-line. Anything here...
~!@#@#$
...
#END
```

How can I take the **3  individual matches** from above string?

I 've try `#BEGIN.*[\s\S]*#END` but I had the trouble with the nested multi-part data string sequence, it only return me **1 match** (from the first `#BEGIN` to the last `#END`). Please help me this case.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Pls share your try, because probably it is just a typo in your code and we can find it easily without writing our own solution.

Comment: I 've added Regex online link to my question, help me, plese. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your regex non-greedy (Lazy) by using the `?`

> *? Lazy Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

```
#BEGIN.*([\s\S]*?)#END
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/fm8qLs/1/)

Comment: It worked well for me. Thank for your help, @Anu Viswan.